# How to tell the relationship between two classes from java code? (Association vs Dependency)

Tags: java, dependencies, uml, associations

Assume that we have a java class Employer:

```
public class Employer{
     public Employer(){
        Gardener gardener = new Gardener();
        gardener.garden();
     }
}
```

and another class Gardener:

```
public class Gardener{
     public void garden(){
        System.out.println("gardening");
     }
}
```

What is the relationship type between Employer and Gardener in this case (Dependency or Association)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is related, but is not a duplicate, since it is looking an answer on an specific example

Comment: @Turing85 I read the other question but still it's not answering mine, this case is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you use an `association` to represent something like a field in a class. On the other hand, naming a parameter type and creating an object in a temporary variable imply a `dependency`.

This is case is a `dependency`.

For more info read [this](https://vaughnvernon.co/?page_id=31).

Comment: You basically just summarized the first answer from the question I referenced as duplicate...

Comment: @Turing85, no... I used it to justify the answer